# Recently Scammed

Tags: windows-7, windows

I've tried everything I know to get my PC working again properly after a bogus email update posing as a Microsoft update. Computer repairs are closed because of the virus but my local man said I could try holding the shift key down and switching the computer off. Will it offer me a menu with the option to restore the computer to a time before the bogus updates or will it do even more harm?

Comment: Microsoft will never send you an e-mail to update your system.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on Computer and select Properties. In the Window that comes up, select (left side) Advanced System Properties. Then in the dialogue that comes up, System Protection Tab.  Click on System Restore. Now see if you can restore to a point prior to the scam.